# Android SharedPreferences, not working. Variable value still = 0

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am looking for help. In one of my activity I have variable id_wallet, I would like to save the value in SharedPreferences and use in other activities. How to do it? Code in brief. I use variable wallet_id in other class.

```
public class ChooseWallet extends AppCompatActivity {


public static int wallet_id;

        listViewChooseWallet.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            wallet_id= (position+1);
            SaveInt("key",wallet_id);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallet number "+(position+1)+" active!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

public void SaveInt(String key, int value){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
public void LoadInt(Context mContext){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    walllet_id  = sharedPreferences.getInt("key", 1);
}
```

Other activity (in short):

```
public class AddOut extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_out);
    addoutbalnce.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString()) > 0 && ChooseWallet.wallet_id != 0 && amount.getText().toString() != null) {
                double amount = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
                amount= (-amount);
                String coment = commentout.getText().toString();
                ChooseWallet wb = new ChooseWallet();
                wb.LoadInt(getApplicationContext());


                db.UpdateAmount(ChooseWallet.wallet_id,amount);
                db.AddTransaction(ChooseWallet.wallet_id, amount, coment, id_cat, date);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString()) < 0 || amount.getText().toString() == null){
                amount.setError("Error!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `LoadInt()` method code in other Activities  to get wallet_id value.

Comment: I try, but method still set wallet_id = 0 or have error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
                      at com.example.xxx.xxx.ChooseWallet.LoadInt(ChooseWallet.java:70)

Comment: dude, Change `LoadInt` to `LoadInt(Context mContext){    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);.....}` then call it by passing `getApplicationContext()` from any Activity

Comment: Ok. I did so, but still does not set the id_wallet.

Comment: Show updated code from both Activities

Comment: You are just calling `wb.LoadInt(getApplicationContext());` method but not using `portfel_id` value any where in `AddOut` Activity

Comment: I use. In database query - db.UpdateAmount and db.AddTransaction/

Comment: Then use `db.UpdateAmount(ChooseWallet.portfel_id,amount);`

Comment: My mistake when translating the names of variables, but it does not work continue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably your emulator don't save sharedpreferences. Try in  your phone start app.